# Loop in line in python without creating a variable that will not be used

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

Here's my code:

```
def generate_float_population(count, size):
    return [generate_float_individual(size) for item in range(count)]
```

My IDE says, variable "item" is not used. I want to know, if there is a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: The usual thing to do in such cases is to use `_` as the variable name.

Comment: What is the Variable `item` used for? You don't Pass it to the function, so you don't need it...

Comment: @linusg: It is used in the list comprehension because he wants `generate_float_individual(size)` to be called `count` times.  He can't do `for in range(count)`, so he does `for item in range(count)` instead.

Comment: Does generate_float_individual() return a different value each time it is called?

Comment: yes @AntoinePinsard, every time generate_float_individual(), returns a different value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function actually has to be called each time then this would work

```
def generate_float_population(count, size)
    return map(generate_float_individual, [size] * count)
```

However if the same value is produced each time then

```
def generate_float_population(count, size)
    return [generate_float_individual(size)] * count
```

Comment: The first code solve.

Answer (score 0):

If `generate_float_individual(size)` should return the same result at each call, you could just do :

```
return [generate_float_individual(size)] * count
```

Comment: even if the return value is equal, if it is also mutable this will not work as expected.

Comment: It is worth noting that if `generate_float_individual()` returns a mutable object, all elements in the list will be modified when any one of them is.

Comment: Yes you are right, should be adapted to the use case. If it returns a list for instance, this should work `return [generate_float_individual(size)[:]] * count`, though adding the overhead of a list copy.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard, adding `[:]` creates a copy of the return value but now all the elements are just a reference to the one copy.  It doesn't solve anything!

Comment: Ah yes right, my mistake.

Comment: actually, i want `generate_float_population(count, size)` returns a list, wich every element of this list, is one element returned `generate_float_individual(size)`. So my list, should to have length equals to count,  dont know if i was clear enough, and sorry about my english.

Comment: The @AntoinePinsard answer solve. Thanks guys, and again i really sorry abou my english, i'm trying to be better.

Answer (score 0):

Since the variable is local to that function... does it really matter that much that it exists? It's gonna disappear soon anyways and is very small.
You should be more worried about creating a needless range(), since that creates a list of n elements (in Python 2.7 at least).

You could go around creating that using xrange, or going the long way around with something like this:

```
class CountDown(object):

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.n <= 0:
            raise StopIteration()
        self.n -= 1
        return self.n
```

And then use it with:

```
def generate_float_population(count, size):
    return [generate_float_individual(size) for item in CountDown(count)]
```

Comment: you raise an excellent point about `range` but the question very obviously states: _My IDE says, variable "item" is not used._   So this doesn't actually solve the original question.